# Need help in recognizing strange image serialization format

Tags: php, image, serialization, encryption

I am facing a problem that cannot be googled I guess, so I am turning to you in despair.

I am meant to restore images from an old self written knowledge database (written in PHP, company internally). Those images were not needed any more some time ago and every concrete implementation for loading them has been removed, for it was obsolete; just the files remain and now its my part to bring them back to check if there is anything within that we still need.

The person who wrote the basement of that construct is long gone now, so there is nobody I could ask...

The images are stored as files on the hard disk (not in a DB) of the server, but not as simple images! They are encrypted somehow and I am not able to resolve the way they are encrypted... but perhaps this is not necessary...

I built some kind of sandbox to determine how methods of the picture loader class are working and reacting and what they deliver me back from analyzing the helper classes I found.

So I came up with this:

```
$ih = new DrImageHelper();
$ih->setImgStore('/home/mic/copy/encrypted_imgs/'); // this dir contains the stange encrypted image files
$imgs = $ih->getImages(DrImageHelper::TYPE_DIAGRAM, 90);

$img_code = DrImageHelper::getImageCode($imgs[0]);

print_r($img_code);
```

(I do not expect you to tell me if the code/usage is correct, no one can tell I guess, for its company-self-written class construct)

This returns something like:

> /9j/4QAYRXhpZgAASUkqAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAP/sABFEdWNreQABAAQAAAA2AAD/4QMZaHR0cDovL25zLmFkb2JlLmNvbS94YXA

(this is only a small part)

I am not quite sure what this is supposed to be and how to handle it, but it seems this is the only/perhaps correct order I can use the class-methods to get a result.. it took me hours to combine method calls without any success.. above is the only snippet that did not crash in fatal and returns a result...

The comment of the getImageCode method tells:
"Returns the decrypted base encoded String to be printed"

Could someone imagine what this could mean?

Does anyone know this format or how to print it/regain images from it?

Can a image really be outputted in form of such a (really long) text string?

Comment: Base64 encoded binary? Maybe `base64_decode()` and write into a file? If that's not it, it's anyone's guess, really.

Comment: *Can a image really be outputted in form of such a (really long) text string?* - yes, it's interesting what you notice when you copy/paste jpgs into WYSIWYG editors on forums ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I once was working with something similar...

So like already said in the comments I also think this is just a base (32 or 64) encoded string (also according to the comment you found to the method). So basically, if so, you do not even need to bother thinking about if its binary or whatever behind the curtain...

For it does not much sense to guess around, I would suggest to just give it a try with the following part of code:

```
$img_string = base64_decode($img_code); // use the var that contains the image code returned by DrImageHelper::getImageCode() here..
print_r($img_string);
```

if you see something, that could indicate a typical picture header (containing something like "PNG" or "JPG" and some plain-text description or something) you are on the right way and may try to simply create a image from this string using:

```
$im = imagecreatefromstring($img_code);
header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
```

(this has nothing to do with the code snipped above and should be go lonesome into another script)

remark: you need one single script for that purpose only containing this second snippet above, because there is one line within which is setting the header type to send...

Now open that script in browser (served by apache/php)... if everything went right you should now see your picture and no more strange code.

To use this decrypted picture within your webpage, you can load that php script as image. This works because the script tells which mime type it belongs to. So assume the second snippet above is copied to a script named "picture_decrypter.php" do this:

```
<img src="picture_decrypter.php" alt="" />
```